# How To Bevel A Single Edge To A Flat Surface?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I want to make this edge to like beveling to a flat surface.
I don't know if i got the term right.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could simply select this edge and bevel it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That option warps the angles on the side, that then would need to be moved into the exact possition they were in separately.
To preserve the geometry:
Split the object down the middle,
Move the two halfs of geometry away from each other and then
Fill in the faces between them.

Comment: @Toby, I don't see what you mean, it doesn't seem to warp the angles, but maybe give your own answer to make it clearer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i solved it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

When the edge is Beveled at the raised edge it only moves those vertices not the vertices in the recesses next to them, changing the angle of the face.
[image]

Separate the two halves
[image]

Then fill in the faces between the selected edges with the <kbd>F</kbd> key.
[image]

Be sure to select all the edges that would touch the fill or it won't connect properly to those edges, like selecting these next three edges:
[image]

Comment: oh ok yes, it really depends on what he wants to do